The resource cannot be found of WebForm file aspx
I have a very legacy project. When I run locally and enable directoryBrowse in Web.Config.
I see below screenshot

If I click CalculationRunner.aspx, it will open a page. So this is good.
As a comparison, when I click PortfolioData.aspx, it gave me error "The resource cannot be found." 404 error.
One thing I really don't understand is that I deleted file PortfolioData.aspx, and recreated a file PortfolioDataTest.aspx. PortfolioDataTest.aspx can be opened on directory browse, but when I change the name to PortfolioData.aspx,(I also changed the name from all the references). The error happens again..
It seems something wrong with the specific naming? (PortfolioData.aspx).
Any help would be appreciated.

Not sure but check if there is some url rewriting or page routing. In Global.asax begin request put a breakdown and try debugging may be

Did you also delete the .cs and designer files and have them be recreated when you created the new .aspx page? (Not sure if it's necessary.)

Be VERY careful when re-naming files. Always use Visual Studio to re-name, and you often have to open up the code behind and check/rename the code class. You can't and do not want to re-name any file outside of Visual Studio, and when you do, you can break many moving parts since the code behind file (and class name) also needs to be re-named.  So, great caution, and you can't just out of the blue re-name files, and especially ones with code tied to the aspx page in mind.
